# Python2.7 split a string with comma

Tags: python-2.7, split

I download a file and the file's string like this:
"124.5","108.5","115","115.5","114","115"

Can I split the string make it look like this:
124.5,108.5,115,115.5,114,115

just split it with comma

thanks a lot !!

Comment: Every answer you got here has value because it all depends how you want the data back: a single string, a list of strings, a list of floats, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '"124.5","108.5","115","115.5","114","115"'
>>> ','.join([item.replace('"', '') for item in s.split(',')])
'124.5,108.5,115,115.5,114,115'
```

### Explanation

- `item.replace('"', '')`: strip quotes from `item`
- `s.split(',')`: returns a list like `['"124.5", "108.5", ... ]`
- `item in s.split(',')`: each of those strings (e.g., '"124.5"')
- `','.join([...])`: Put it back together as a comma-separated string

Obviously if you don't do the last step (`','.join`), you have them as a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes:

```
x = x.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '"124.5","108.5","115","115.5","114","115"'
>>> nums = [float(x) for x in s.replace('"', '').split(',')]
>>> nums
[124.5, 108.5, 115, 115.5, 114, 115]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
','.join(s[1:-1] for s in '"124.5","108.5","115","115.5","114","115"'.split(','))
```